# Vector array of pointers of type struct in CPP

Tags: c++, vector

I have a structure:

```
struct node{

int data;
int rank;
node* ptr;
};
```

After that I have defined a class as follows: The structure is outside the class.

```
class A{

     private:
     vector<node*> update(int searchKey);

     ....some more functions...

     const int maxLevel;
     };
```

Now when I write definition of this function I write it as follow:

```
 std::vector<node*>A::update(int searchKey)
{
   vector<node*> result(maxLevel,0);   // 0 signifies a nullptr here

 .......some code that fills the vector declared above......

  return result;
}
```

The value of maxLevel is initialized in the constructor for the class as follow:

```
A::A():maxLevel(10)
{
  some more code...
}
```

Running the code gives me the following error:

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:1252:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector::value_type {aka node*}’ [-fpermissive]
>       _M_fill_initialize(static_cast(__n), __value);

I have tried many changes but I keep getting the error. What is that I am doing wrong? Please let me know if I am missing some details in the question.Thanks

Comment: [Afraid I can't reproduce it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37126299444a9c57). You are going to need a much better [mcve].

Comment: @StoryTeller I can reprodce it with clang ;-) As the error says it is because of -fpermissive flag, which your online compiler does not use

Comment: yes the same code runs fine in CodeBlocks IDE but when I try to run it through console with g++, it throws this error.

Comment: @skii CoideBlocks is not a C++ compiler.  What compiler is CodeBlocks using?  Isn't it g++?

Comment: @Stacker - 0 is convertible, implicitly, to a null pointer constant for any pointer type. If there's an error for 0, there must be an error for `nullptr`, since both require a conversion.

Comment: @Stacker link to web compiler?

Comment: @skii -- BTW, if you left out the `,0`  and just let the vector default initialize itself (`vector<node*> result(maxLevel)`), you would have had the null pointers in the vector aiutomatically.

Comment: @Stacker - And just to further drive that point home, here's the online [Clang I used, with `-fpermissive`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c27a378b90c47abf). Accepting it without a hitch.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry for the late reply, I've been in a meeting. Here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5779642333dd172

Comment: @Stacker - You didn't specify a standard revision flag, I did. *That* affected the behavior of `-fpermissive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
vector<node*> result(maxLevel, nullptr);
```

instead to solve that error. We don't use 0 or NULL for null pointers any more since C++11.

Usually it is better not to initialize the whole vector with null pointers and then overwriting these, but to reserve space first and then push the final values instead.

```
result.reserve(maxLevel);
...
for (auto i = 0; i < maxLevel; ++i)
  result.push_back(/* pointer to new node */)
```

Comment: yes this solves the problem . But why does the error poiting to invalid conversion from int to <node*> ??

Comment: @skii - Because your example is not demonstrative, really. So this is the correct answer, to a question you *should* have asked.

Answer (score -1):

vector result(maxLevel,0);   // 0 signifies a nullptr here

You are trying to instantiate vector with maxlevel and 0.
maxlevel seems like a type of integer.
There are no constructor in std::vector which could match this call.
This is the reason for the error.

Comment: This is BS! [`vector(size_type count, const T& value)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) with `T=node*` is a valid constructor.

Comment: `maxLevel` is convertible to `size_type` and `0` to `const node*&`.